# Как и чем заменить разделитель батча GO?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sybase

Написал программу, которая посылает sql запросы на сервер Ase Sybase.
Работает это чудо с помощью AdoNetCore.AseClient и в целом успешно с этим справляется.

Ключевой особенностью является отправка запроса сразу на несколько выбранных серверов. Это удобно, но когда дело доходит до длинных процедур с разделителями GO, тут он успешно сообщает:

Incorrect syntax near 'go'

Я знаю почему так происходит, так как Transact-SQL не поддерживает этот разделитель. Безусловно GO оператор распознается SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), sqlcmd и osql, но меня интересует костыль, который будет работать на AseClient.

Comment: Do you know? @Michael Gardner

Comment: Писать запросы в батче через точку с запятой: `;`. Использовать метод [NextResult](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader#retrieving-multiple-result-sets-using-nextresult).

Comment: Уведомление через `@` получит только тот, кто отметился в теме (комментариях). Поэтому бесполезно призывать кого-то постороннего. Тем более звать англоговорящего на русскоязычный сайт.

Comment: Ничем. Или заменять на ;, или решать вручную на отдельные запросы при выполнении по go.

Comment: Причём в некоторый случаях ; не прокатит - например, тело триггера - это не код от begin до end, а весь код от create до конца батча

Comment: @Alexander Petrov
Не будет работать **;**

Answer (score 1):

Самый надежный способ — изменить свою программу так, чтоб она разделяла входной файл на части по маркеру `GO` и отправляла их отдельными запросами.